# Adobe Javascript Calculation Errors

Tags: javascript, adobe, calculation

I want to check fields "Code1 to Code 32" for anything starting with "A" and ending with "B".  I want the count to output to the field "Total1".  I input the code under properties of "Total1" in the custom calculation.  The Javascript doesn't calculate.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
  var f = this.getField("Code" + i).valueAsString;
  var v = f.valueAsString;
  if (v.charAt(0) == "A" && v.charAt(v.length - 1) == "B") total++;
}
event.value = total;
```